# How can I insert the backslash character ( \ ) before quotation marks (" ") in Emacs?

Tags: text-editing, quote, insert, paredit, backslash

I am running Emacs and writing on the **scratch-buffer**. This is my [config file](https://github.com/pdelfino/dotfiles/blob/main/.emacs.d/init.el).
After executing `describe-mode`, this is the list of minor modes running:

```
Enabled minor modes: Auto-Composition Auto-Compression Auto-Encryption
Blink-Cursor Column-Number Delete-Selection Display-Line-Numbers
Doom-Modeline Eldoc Electric-Indent File-Name-Shadow Font-Lock
Global-Display-Line-Numbers Global-Eldoc Global-Font-Lock
Global-Git-Commit Global-Wakatime Ivy-Prescient Ivy-Rich Line-Number
Magit-Auto-Revert Override-Global Paredit Rainbow-Delimiters
Shell-Dirtrack Show-Paren Transient-Mark Wakatime Which-Key
```

This the problem demonstrated as a gif. When I try to insert backslash before quotes, something weird happens after I press `C-f` (to move the cursor forward). I happen to be stuck and it is not possible to leave, except for deleting everything:

[image]

How solve it?

Obs.: Currently, I have a hack. Basically, I execute command `query-replace`, pick `"` character and then choose as a replacement `\"`. But I feel there must be a better way.

Comment: What happens if you press `C-f` again? What mode is the buffer in? What minor modes are enabled? What does `C-h c C-f` say? What happens if you do `C-b` instead or some other control sequence? The only way I can reproduce the behavior in my `*scratch*` buffer (which is in `lisp-interaction` mode with a bunch of minor modes enabled)  is if I press `C-q` before I press `C-f`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a feature of paredit. If you look at the minibuffer (the line at the bottom of your Emacs window) when you press `\`, you'll see you're being prompted for "Character to escape:". The next character you enter will be inserted with a backslash in front of it.

This happens because you're using paredit, and paredit provides features for managing parentheses, quotes, and backslashes for you. If you want to enter a new quote symbol with a backslash in front of it, you press `\`, then `"`, and then paredit enters it for you. If you want to add a `\` in front of a character that's already on the screen, you need to use the `quoted-insert` command: `C-q \`.

There are links to more documentation, and a very nice demo on youtube, at the [Emacs Wiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ParEdit).

If you want a more conventional interface, you need to remove paredit. It can definitely be a bit confusing to get used to, but a lot of people find it quite useful.